# Add a prefix of +1 to a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I remove all non 10 digit numbers from a string, and add a +1 to the front of it if it doesn't exist yet?

Here's the regex code I have:

```
phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9.\,]/g, '');
phoneNumber = '+1' + phoneNumber;
```

but this won't work if `phoneNumber` already has `+1`. How can I make it that the regex first removes all non numerical, and adds a prefix of +1?

Comment: What do you mean by 'all non 10 digit numbers' ? Can you add a sample and intended output?

Comment: ... Either check to see if it's there before adding it, or remove it and add it on later. Regexes can contain multiple expressions, for example, a `+1`, so you could simply remove all `+1` and non-digits, then add it on later. It's unclear what you mean by "non 10 digit numbers", if you're aiming for typos, don't--validate against the number of digits after you're done, don't alter user input willy-nilly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to check for an optional +1 in front.

```
"+167t6if6".replace(/(\+1)?[^0-9.\,]./g, '');
phoneNumber = '+1' + phoneNumber;
```

This will match zero or one occurrences of +1, and any number of non digits.

`(\+1)?` This checks for optional +1

The period at the end makes any number of non-digits match - this is in the case that there are no non-digits after the +1.